# FQL error 'failed to open stream failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error in '

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql

I am 2 facebook accounts.
I use one for testing (has 600 friends) and other for development (5 friends). I am trying get all the ids of a users friend using the code

```
function get_photo($access_token){
    // Run fql query 
    $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    . '/fql?q=SELECT+pid+,object_id+,owner+FROM+photo+WHERE+owner+=+me()+OR+owner+IN+(SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1+=+me())+LIMIT+50'
    . '&access_token=' . $access_token;
     // First logically check the result, TRUE: Result is passed to $fql_query_result.
  //                                   FALSE: $flq_query_result = 0 or false.
  $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url)?file_get_contents($fql_query_url):0;
  // Only json_decode the result if it was valid.
  $fql_query_obj = (!$fql_query_result == 0) ? json_decode($fql_query_result, true) : "FQL was not a valid query";

  //display results of fql query
  echo '<pre>';
  //print_r("query results:");
  print_r($fql_query_obj);
  echo '</pre>';
  return $fql_query_obj;}
```

I have obtained the following permissions
user_about_me,read_stream,user_activities,email,user_location,user_photos,friends_photos,publish_actions,user_birthday,user_likes,read_insights,read_insights,user_status';

The problem is the code works from the developers account but gives the following error with the test account.

```
file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com//fql?q=SELECT+pid+,object_id+,owner+FROM+photo+WHERE+owner+=+me()+OR+owner+IN+(SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1+=+me())+LIMIT+50&access_token=AAAEEKwQN3CMBAEUC6DqfakwkSZCdeLI2zk5Ec2evZBJvZB14Nh9e4ZBs8bOOw36F9T2winWRyzSx3vSCcWOl4A80AgcOjEvft1sbW7MLeEE2cyVPCIAb): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error in /var/www/JMJ_test/facebook_include1.php on line 190
FQL was not a valid query
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found this problem with other APIs. Normally, it's nothing wrong with the code, but the amount of friends on the account. The dev one works, only 5 friends, whereas the testing one doesn't because it has 600 friends. I will try and find the limit for you in a second. 
**Edit**

Sorry, I could not find the limit, but I read something about 600 requests per 600 seconds per iP. Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought that might be the problem so I used +LIMIT+50 in my query . But still it doesnot help!

Comment: Ha, I just saw that. Sorry I couldn't help.